# Gunicorn ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a django application by following [this](https://blog.alura.com.br/fazendo-o-deploy-de-uma-aplicacao-django/) tutorial. 
At the time of starting gunicorn, I use this command: `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 wsgi:application`, being inside the folder where my wsgi.py is located.

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And I get the following error:

```
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7786] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7786] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (7786)
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7786] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7789] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7789
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7789] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/renato-sfera/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7789] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7789)
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7786] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-07-19 20:54:39 -0300] [7786] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

What can it be? I am available to post what is necessary to solve the problem

Comment: Have you installed Django using `pip install django`?

Comment: Yes, django and the others dependencies are installed

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for the past two days

1. Make sure you are running the command from your project's directory (not from the wsgi folder).
2. Make sure it's the right version of django.
3. Try running in virtual environment.
4. Install uwsgi module:

   pip3 install uwsgi

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this error. I had to force install my requirements in the virtualenv

With the venv active:

```
pip install -I -r requirements.txt
```

Initially I just forced installed django but it was missing its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential libssl-dev -y

I was helped by such a team, maybe not everything is needed there.